# JS/PHP: Is there any way to get image height without waiting for window to load first?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got an image and I want to fire a JS function - but it's dependant on the height of the image. Something like below:

```
if($(".displayArea").find("img").height() > 500){
     //Important function comes in...
     myFunction();
}
```

The problem is I have to use `$(window).load()` to get the height of the image and that takes a long time, I'd like to be able to fire `myFunction()` on `$(document).ready()` and not later.

Is there anyway to use `JS/jQuery or PHP` to figure out that the image will be more or less than 500px and fire the function accordingly?

Comment: Maybe helpful [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) in _php_

Comment: getimagesize worked thanks! If you add an answer I'll mark it

Comment: You can also try listening for image onload events, and check the image height when the event fires.

Comment: @CafeCoder will that not happen after the `doc ready` event though?

Comment: @user1775598 Yeah, I misread the question. Image onload events typically fire after doc ready as images take some time to download. If you must run the script before the images are downloaded, getimagesize will have to do.

Comment: @user1775598 However, as running getimagesize for every hit can be inefficient, it would be better if you can store the getimagesize results in the db and use those values instead.

Comment: I've only got one image on the page who's size I need to calculate. Is it worth storing that data in DB, or is it alright to just use getimagesize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *PHP* you can get more information about an image file by using [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). Be aware that performing this operation thousands of times can be costly, so you may wish to cache the results somehow.